# Does GTK kill CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, gtk

I have heard that GTK covers all controls so that developers do not care about CSS and HTML any more. Do you guys agree with this idea?

Comment: what!?⁉‽ could you please clarify your question

Comment: Excellent use of the interrobang.

Comment: I personally agree. Just stop this interwebs thing already.

Comment: This question is so wrong in so many regards I don’t know what makes me puke first.

Comment: What I don't see is why people want to close this as "subjective and argumentative." I don't see how a non-sequitur is subjective _or_ argumentative. If you guys voted for, say, "not a real question", I could get behind that.

Comment: @erik: i’m glad someone knows it ;)

Comment: GTK will add CSS themes support: http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2008/07/experimental-gtk-theme-engine-will-add-css-support.ars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, GTK is not a web toolkit (if we're talking about the same GTK), so it doesn't conflict with CSS and HTML in any way, so developers who did care about CSS and HTML still do and those who do not, didn't care before GTK either.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there's a lot of discussion on the gtk-devel mailing list about using CSS for GTK theming.